# I set up CORS in my Rails app, but I still get the error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, cors

I have it in the gemfile `gem 'rack-cors', require: 'rack/cors'`. I did bundle install.

I also set it up in the config/initializers/cors.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'

    resource '*',
      headers: :any,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
   end
 end
```

I did restart the server after.

Here is the error I get:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:3000/articles' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

Here is my repo [Portfolio_App](https://github.com/Elijbet/Portfolio_App_2019).

Comment: What is output of `curl -I -X OPTIONS -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST" -H "Origin: example.org" localhost:3000/articles` ?

Comment: `HTTP/1.1 200 OK  
Content-Type: text/plain  
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *  
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD  
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:   
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000  
Transfer-Encoding: chunked`

Comment: Also please post js that issues that XMLHttpRequest

Comment: This has been marked as a duplicate question but I don't know if it is. [CORS Error: “requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http…”] doesn't explain where I could have been running into a problem on a Rails app. My question was about setting up CORS on Rails. It might have the same answer as the other question at the end, but it's not the same question. I wouldn't have known this question answers my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `vue_portfolio/src/components/Articles.vue` you have `axios.get('localhost:3000/articles')`, without protocol it is not absolute not relative, browser thinks that you're trying to connect to host `3000` via protocol `localhost` and does not allow.

Change it to

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3000/articles')
```

or

```
axios.get('/articles')
```

(the latter is for same-origin, CORS is not needed in this case)